# How to add recursively modules in shiny through reactivity

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm new to shiny and
I'm trying to create an app in which
after the first selection from the user, a function does
some manipulation to a predefined dataset and has to open 
a new selector UI.
In that new selector UI the user selects again a new value,
another function does some manipulation to the new dataset and so on
for 3~4 more times.

> edit:
>
> Plus each time the user selects the value it will open the next `selectUI` 
>   and when he does the selection the next ui will pop.
>   I used some examples from the shiny website but I get each time a different error:

1)

```
     Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7178
            Warning: Error in if: argument is not interpretable as logical
              52: server [#12]
            Error in if (reactive(input$Strength_1)) { : 
              argument is not interpretable as logical
```

2)

```
    Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7178
    Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
      61: stop
      60: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
      59: getCurrentContext
      55: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
      54: $.reactivevalues
      52: server [#12]
    Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
      Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

3)

```
 Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7178
 Warning: Error in force: argument "ui" is missing, with no default [No stack trace available]
 Warning: Error in : evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)? 93: <Anonymous>
```

> The dataset:

```
Attr_scores %>% head %>% dput
structure(list(scope = c("Sel1", "Sel2", "Sel3", "Sel4", "Sel5", 
"Sel6"), A1 = c(14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15), A2 = c(13, 14, 14, 14, 
15, 15), A3 = c(13, 13, 14, 13, 12, 15), A4 = c(13, 13, 13, 12, 
12, 11), A5 = c(13, 13, 10, 12, 11, 8), A6 = c(12, 10, 8, 11, 
11, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

> The functions:

```
Attr_score_select <- function(x){
    Attr_scores %>%
        filter(scope == x) %>%
        pivot_longer(-scope) %>% 
        select(value) %>% 
        group_by(value) %>% 
        summarise(n=n())
}
Attr_score_remove <- function(df, score){
    df %>% 
        mutate(n = ifelse(value == score, n-1, n)) %>% 
        mutate(n = ifelse(n == 0, NA, n)) %>% 
        drop_na()     
}
```

> The ui:

```
## ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamically generated user interface components"),
  selectInput(inputId = 'scores',
              label = "Choose scores", 
              choices = c(Choose='', Attr_scores$scope ),
              selectize=TRUE),
  uiOutput("Strength_ui")
)
```

> The server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  Scores <- reactive(Attr_score_select(input$scores))

  output$Strength_ui <- renderUI({
    #Strength
           selectInput('Strength_1', 
                       label = "Choose Strength score for your character:", 
                       c(Choose='', as.character(Scores()$value))
           )
  })
 # from here on it creates the errors ------------

 if (input$Strength_1){
    observeEvent(input$Strength_1,{
               Scores <- reactive( Scores() %>% 
                                     Attr_score_remove(input$Strength_1))
               insertUI(
                  #Dexterity
                  selectInput('Dexterity_1',
                   label = "Choose Dexterity score for your character:",
                   c(Choose='',as.character(Scores()$value))
                  )  

               ) 
              })

    }
 # if you remove it then it runs ---------------
  }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fully understand the topic you work on, but I'd use reactive expressions and renderUI to build such an app.

Here comes my solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

Attr_scores <- structure(list(scope = c(
  "Sel1", "Sel2", "Sel3", "Sel4", "Sel5",
  "Sel6"
), A1 = c(14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15), A2 = c(
  13, 14, 14, 14,
  15, 15
), A3 = c(13, 13, 14, 13, 12, 15), A4 = c(
  13, 13, 13, 12,
  12, 11
), A5 = c(13, 13, 10, 12, 11, 8), A6 = c(
  12, 10, 8, 11,
  11, 8
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Attr_score_select <- function(x){
  Attr_scores %>%
    filter(scope == x) %>%
    pivot_longer(-scope) %>% 
    select(value) %>% 
    group_by(value) %>% 
    summarise(n=n())
}
Attr_score_remove <- function(df, score){
  df %>% 
    mutate(n = ifelse(value == score, n-1, n)) %>% 
    mutate(n = ifelse(n == 0, NA, n)) %>% 
    drop_na()     
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamically generated user interface components"),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "scores",
    label = "Choose scores",
    choices = c(Choose = "", Attr_scores$scope),
    selectize = TRUE
  ),
  uiOutput("Strength_ui"),
  uiOutput("Dexterity_1")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  Scores <- reactive(Attr_score_select(input$scores))
  output$Strength_ui <- renderUI({
    #Strength
    selectInput('Strength_1', 
                label = "Choose Strength score for your character:", 
                Scores()$value)
  })
  Scores1 <- reactive(Scores() %>% Attr_score_remove(input$Strength_1) %>% select(value))
  output$Dexterity_1 = renderUI(
        selectInput('Dexterity_1', label = "Choose Dexterity score for your character:",Scores1())
        )  

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Regards
Paweł

Comment: Thanks a lot, Pawel, so the problem is that I'm using the same variable (Scope) for functions that are nested plus the insertUI. My main thing is that I want to show the third and UI at first but only make it visible when the user has selected the 2nd value ('Strength_1') and then to do it also for the next the one after that etc...

Comment: Nesting is not always good idea - in your case it made an infinite loop. Your goal is to hide the Dexterity Input before user selects Scores and Strength. What should happen, if user decides to change Scores after preliminary selection Scores/Strength?

Comment: I don't know if this the best idea but he has to restart from Scores again. The idea is to create a bucket of the scores. When the user selects one of the scores of the bucket he should not be able to use it again. I thought that the easiest way is to do it sequentially selecting each one and removing it each time. In the end, there are 6 scores that the user has to select, Strength and Dexterity is the 2 out of 6 so I have to add also the selector UI at least 3 more times.

Comment: Does it mean, that when user selects Score "Sel1", then, chooses Strength and then changes Score to "Sel2" he should not be able to choose "Sel1" anymore?

Comment: Ah, no. As you can see the function Attr_score_remove  calculates which scores remain to be selected every time the user selects one of the choices that derive from the dataset. As long as he has selected the dataset everything else can be selected sequentially.

Comment: In case of reactive expressions, all udates are done automatically. Does my solution work as you expected, or something should be modified?